# How to open .dat file in Mysql or output JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, file

I'm a customer support engineer who has recently started programming.
I have received a .dat file and been asked to parse it due to my project experience.
I consulted with the technical manager, and he mentioned that it is a file format for the MSSQL database. I attempted to open it as a text file, but it displayed as garbled characters. I also tried using Node.js to read the file content with UTF-8 encoding, but it still showed null and garbled characters. Do you have any suggestions or directions on how I can effectively analyze this file and potentially fix the displayed garbled characters?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwLtb.png)

This is the approach I attempted to use.
Should I use a specific encoding to translate it?
I'm completely clueless, please help me out. I would greatly appreciate it.